# How to generate a button inside a BoundField on GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm implementing a date calendar with 12 by 31 days per month. Where I need to put a button inside a boundfield or cell on a gridview. Example, row 2 cell 3 generate a button.

Example Output:

### |   1       |    2      |   3       |   4       |   5       | so on...

### JAN | [Button]  | [Button]  | [Button]  | [Button]  | [Button]  | so on...

### FEB | [Button]  | [Button]  | [Button]  | [Button]  | [Button]  | so on...

### MAR | [Button]  | [Button]  | [Button]  | [Button]  | [Button]  | so on...

Comment: You can use `<asp:buttonfield>`

Comment: Or use `TemplateField`